# Scrollable buttons from left to right?

Tags: android

I am trying to scroll with buttons from left to right.
Instead of scrolling up and down. How would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a horizontal scroll view.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html